# Issue with displaying random text from an array on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Novice here. Followed a tutorial and made a Flappy Bird clone in vanilla javascript. I have a much better understanding of canvas and the logic behind javascript games now, and I've had a lot of fun tweaking the code.

I'm currently trying to display one of three random strings from an array every 3 points scored.

This is my code:

```
 var motivation = ["Radical!", "Tubular!", "Cowabunga, dude!"];



  var motivationRandom = motivation[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
 motivation.length)];

  if (score % 3 === 0 && score !==0){
      ctx.fillstyle = "#000";
      ctx.font = "50px Impact";
      ctx.fillText(motivationRandom, 50, cvs.height-50);
    }
```

When the score is a multiple of 3, the text will rapidly shift between one of the three strings in the array until another point is scored and the conditions of the if statement is no longer met.

It would be awesome if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: You'd probably need to show us a bit more of your code, so we can at least get when this is called. From the described behavior I'll assume it's in the animation loop. The solution would then be to store `motivationRandom` in an outer scope, and to update it only when the score do change.

Comment: This along with the other reply fixed the issue. I'm still working out all the nuances concerning scope. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the canvas with your random string on your desired score.

I have done a demonstration of this on button click here.

```js
var score=1;
var motivation = ["Radical!", "Tubular!", "Cowabunga, dude!"];

function updateCanvas(){
var cvs = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

ctx.font = "15px Georgia";
 var motivationRandom = motivation[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
 motivation.length)];
//console.log(motivationRandom,score);
  if (score % 3 === 0 && score !==0){
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);   
     ctx.fillstyle = "#000";
      ctx.font = "50px Impact";
    ctx.fillText(motivationRandom, 10, cvs.height-50);
    }
   } 
     $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#AddButton').click( function() {
                    score++ ;
                  updateCanvas();
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="Button" id='AddButton' value="+" />
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
```

Comment: This along with kaiidos fixed the problem, much appreciated.